# Using AutoIT to access windows security dialog

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, autoit

I have been using below code for a while to click on all non-web application based popups. ex windows security login popup in case my web app tries to upload a file. All worked fine so far all of sudden the same code stops working and hangs at the popup screen but works if i have break point in my visual studio code.

```
WinWaitActive("Windows Security",,7)
ControlClick("Windows Security",,"Button2")
```

I have crossed checked the OK button name nothing has change but the above code refuse to work any more. Using Visual studio 2010 vb.net.

Comment: I am using Selenium and AutoIT within my .Net project importing library and the language used is vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ImageSearchDLL?  It allows you to take a screenshot of a button (or image, link, etc.) and use it as a reference for where to click.  For more usage info and to download sample code look here:  http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/65748-image-search-library/page-4

Comment: I am trying to avoid more libraries AutoIT tool should work if it worked for so long and i fail to understand what could have made it stop working all of a sudden. I have also tried restarting machine.

Comment: You have a timeout of 7 seconds on the WinWaitActive function.  What if you removed the timeout, or increased it?

Comment: Tried both still not happy just gets hanged at the first line :(